# Formatting Localized Strings with Multiple Values

Tags: swift, localization

I've created a localized string that takes the form similar to

```
"text_key" = "Collected %d out of %d";
```

and am using the following formatter:

```
let numberOfItems = 2
let totalNumberOfItems = 10
let format = NSLocalizedString("text_key", comment: "Says how many items (1st var) were collected out of total possible (2nd var)")
let text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, numberOfItems, totalNumberOfItems)
```

Which gives

```
"Collected 2 out of 10"
```

However I can imagine that in some languages it would be more natural to have these values appear in a different order resulting in a non-sensical string such as

```
"Out of a possible 2 items you collected 10"
```

I cannot find a simple way to encode this using the standard Swift library such as

```
"text_key" = "Out of a possible {2%d} items you collected {1%d}"
```

and can see this getting cumbersome hardcoding these as more values are added.

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String.localizedStringWithFormat()` works with “positional arguments”
`%n$`. In your case

```
"text_key" = "Out of a possible %2$d items you collected %1$d";
```

would do the trick.

These are documented in [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html):

> Conversions can be applied to the nth argument after the format in the argument list, rather than to the next unused argument. In this case, the conversion specifier character % (see below) is replaced by the sequence "%n$", where n is a decimal integer in the range [1,{NL_ARGMAX}], giving the position of the argument in the argument list.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I use %1@ and %2@, the output remains the same if I swap those around.

Comment: @AaronBratcher: I have checked it once again: With the code from the question and the Localizable.strings entry from my answer I get as text: “Out of a possible 10 items you collected 2”. – Did you use `%1$d` and `%2$d` with the dollar sign?

Comment: I'm not using numbers, I'm using strings

Comment: @AaronBratcher: Still works for me, with `"Out of a possible %2$@ items you collected %1$@"` as the format string.

Comment: Ah, I had omitted the $. Thanks