# SwiftUI localize multiple string interpolations

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I would like to pass more than one variable into my localized string.
For example I want to localize the string `"My Name is \(name) and I am \(age) years old"`.

To localize a string with a single string interpolation, I can do this in my string file:
`"helloName%@" = "Hello my name is %@";`
But what can I do if I want to localize a text with two ore more string interpolations?
Note that the string interpolations will be on different positions in different languages...
`"name%@age%@" = "My Name is %@ and I am @% years old";`
That won´t work because you can't differentiate the interpolated strings or integers and you
don´t know where to put it in the translated string.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a fan of having string placeholder in localized keys. I'd prefer "nameAndAge" over "name%@age%@". With `"My Name is %@ and I am %d years old"`, I'd go then with `NSLocalizedString(format: "nameAndAge", myNameString, myIntAge)` (or something like that)

Comment: Thank you really much for you help! What is %d doing? And does NSLocalizedString also work in SwiftUI? I thought it was only for UIKit...

Comment: "%d" is a for an `Int`. And `Text()` accepts a `String`(returned value by `NSLocalizedString()`, so, yes it's usable in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, just use more placeholders. You need to match the types correctly of course:

```json
"helloNameAndAge %@ %lld" = "My name is %@ and I am %lld years old";
```

```swift
let name = "Max"
let age = 21
Text("helloNameAndAge \(name) \(age)")
```

The position of the placeholders in the localized versions don't matter. All that matters is that the ordering is the same as in the key.

See [Formatting Localized Strings with Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51369282) if you need to change the ordering too. Here is how your example could be switched (the Swift code doesn't change):

```json
"helloNameAndAge %@ %lld" = "I am %2$lld years old, my name is %1$@";
```

Ps. A good reference for placeholder format is [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: Thank you really much! But couldn't I somehow make the placeholders in the localized string identifiable, so that I know exactly which parameter I'm using at which point in my localized string? Because maybe the order of the parameters is different in some languages..

Comment: In fact it seems it is possible, see [Formatting Localized Strings with Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51369282)

Comment: Answer updated to include this information.

Comment: This is the solution! You can identify the different string interpolations by puttin a number and a $ in between the % and the @ (like this: %1$@, %2$@ ). I appreciate it